# Next and Previous Button for Pages

Tags: views

I have created a 'Content Type' names it Stories. And have created 30 new pages for each stories using the same Content Type. Now how can i add **Previous and Next Button** under each stories?

Any Article or Video tutorial will be appreciated

Thank You,
Mazhar
P.S I am using D8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that one relatively easy way without relying on any additional modules is to use the book module that comes with drupal core.

If you put the nodes in a book then you can use the book navigation's previous and next button.

You can override [book-navigation.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21book%21templates%21book-navigation.html.twig/8.2.x) to remove elements of the book navigation that you don't need.

Comment: Thanks Rooby,

I am a newbie in Drupal, thank you. Liked your suggestion very much. I looked for the video and found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuItYbS9Rlo&t=4s

I am gonna try it later and if I get stuck I will seek your help again. 

Thanks
Mazhar

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old thread, but for benefit of users looking for an answer in 2020 for Drupal 8 (8.8+) and 9, try out https://www.drupal.org/project/related_nodes_block.

It does not require any taxonomy terms, and it supports Prev/Next, First/Last, Most/Least Viewed and Random, of same content-type or others, you choose.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the module.